# How do I redirect stderr and stdout to file for a Ruby script?

Tags: ruby, redirect, stdout, stderr

How do I redirect stderr and stdout to file for a Ruby script?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459330/how-do-i-temporarily-redirect-stderr-in-ruby

Answer (score 70):

From *within a Ruby script*, you can redirect `stdout` and `stderr` with the [`IO#reopen`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M000890) method.

```
# a.rb
$stdout.reopen("out.txt", "w")
$stderr.reopen("err.txt", "w")

puts 'normal output'
warn 'something to stderr'
```

```
$ ls
a.rb
$ ruby a.rb
$ ls
a.rb    err.txt out.txt
$ cat err.txt 
something to stderr
$ cat out.txt 
normal output
```

Comment: How can normal $stdout be restored again afterwards?

Comment: why should we use reopen method ? it's mean that if "out.txt" is not exists, it will be created?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22777806/1287376) on how to restore $stdout afterwards.

Comment: You'll need to `$stdout.sync = true` and `$stderr.sync = true` if you hope to, say, tail the file while lines are being written.  Otherwise, the lines won't be written out until the process closes, or something else like that flushes the streams.

Answer (score 13):

Note: reopening of the standard streams to /dev/null is a good old method of helping a process to become a daemon. For example:

```
# daemon.rb
$stdout.reopen("/dev/null", "w")
$stderr.reopen("/dev/null", "w")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "helping a process become a daemon"?

Comment: In UNIX in order to make a program a daemon the programmer should not merely fork it into background but also redirect it's standard IO streams. Are you familiar with this?

Comment: Note: If using built-in `Process.daemon` it can do this for you. See [docs here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Process.html#method-c-daemon).

Answer (score 10):

```
def silence_stdout
  $stdout = File.new( '/dev/null', 'w' )
  yield
ensure
  $stdout = STDOUT
end
```

Comment: Good, but this is better, in case STDOUT was something else. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4459463/26604

Answer (score 4):

```
./yourscript.rb 2>&1 > log.txt
```

will redirect stdout and stderr to the same file.

Comment: Assuming you are running on *nix

Comment: @Steve: I think `>` works on Windows - I'm not sure about `2>` though.

Comment: This answer also makes assumptions about what shell the user is using, even within *nix.  Some shells have different redirection styles, for instance the default behavior of zsh.

Comment: It does not. Redirection order matters. It first redirects stderr to stdout, making stderr a COPY of the initial stdout, then redirect stdout to the  file. Only stdout is redirected to a file. to redirect both stdout and stderr to the same file, use `./yourscript.rb > log.txt  2>&1`. As of 2022, some shells support `&>` or `>&` to redirect both descriptors at the same time (bash 5.2 or zsh 5.8 for example)

Answer (score 3):

A full example with $stdout and $stderr redirected to a file and how to restore the initial behavior.

```rb
#!/usr/bin/ruby

logfile = "/tmp/testruby.log"

@original_stdout = $stderr.dup
@original_stderr = $stderr.dup
$stdout.reopen(logfile, "w")
$stdout.sync = true
$stderr.reopen($stdout)


def restore_stdout
  $stdout.reopen(@original_stdout)
  $stderr.reopen(@original_stderr)
end

def fail_exit(msg)
  puts "- #{msg}" # to the logfile
  restore_stdout
  $stderr.puts "+ #{msg}" # to standard error
  exit!
end

def success_exit(msg)
  puts "- #{msg}" # to the logfile
  restore_stdout  
  $stdout.puts "+ #{msg}" # to standard output
  exit
end

puts "This message goes to the file"

success_exit "A successful exit message"
```