# How do I temporarily redirect stderr in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stdout, yield, stderr

This is my code (recompilation of [How do I temporarily redirect stderr in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459330/how-do-i-temporarily-redirect-stderr-in-ruby/4459463#4459463) (which can't be used because of native extension writes):

```
def silence_stdout(log = '/dev/null')
 orig = $stdout.dup
 $stdout.reopen(File.new(log, 'w'))
 begin
   yield
 ensure
   $stdout = orig
 end
end

silence_stdout('ttt.log') do
   #do something
end
```

But I have a problem, the file is filled with the code only after the puma stops (Ctrl + C).
Probably should I close the file? But I do not understand how to do it. All my attempts to close the file end as **"log writing failed. closed stream"** or **"no block given (yield)"**.
I ask for advice.