# How can I use IO#reopen with a StringIO?

Tags: ruby, file-io, stderr

I would like to capture stderr into a variable in memory, without using a file on the filesystem. (This is because if the process is `kill -9`'ed, the file, even if it is a Tempfile, will not be deleted.)

There is a solution for this at [How do I temporarily redirect stderr in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459330/how-do-i-temporarily-redirect-stderr-in-ruby), but its strategy is to assign a StringIO to `$stderr`. This will not work if the value of $stderr was copied prior to the reassignment, nor will it work if `STDERR` is used. As evidence:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

stderr_sav = $stderr
$stderr = File.open(File::NULL, 'w')
$stderr.puts    'Using $stderr'
stderr_sav.puts 'Using stderr_sav'
STDERR.puts     'Using STDERR'

# Outputs:

# Using stderr_sav
# Using STDERR
```

In contrast, using `reopen` works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

stderr_sav = $stderr
$stderr.reopen(File.new(File::NULL, 'w'))
$stderr.puts    'Using $stderr'
stderr_sav.puts 'Using stderr_sav'
STDERR.puts     'Using STDERR'

# Outputs:

# [nothing]
```

Unfortunately, passing a `StringIO` to `reopen` does not work:

```
`reopen': no implicit conversion of StringIO into String (TypeError)
```

Is there any way to accomplish the capturing of `$stderr` without using a file?

Answer (score 0):

How about a proxy which temporary delegate `IO#puts` to `StringIO#puts`

```rb
stderr_sav = $stderr

# delegate
$stdclone = $stderr.clone
$temp = StringIO.new

[:puts].each do |m|
  if $temp.respond_to?(m)
    $stderr.define_singleton_method "#{m}" do |*args, &block|
      $temp.send(m, *args, &block)
    end
  end
end

# test
$stderr.puts 'secret1' # nothing
STDERR.puts 'secret2' # nothing
stderr_sav.puts 'secret3' # nothing

new_strerr = IO.new(1)
new_strerr.puts "not secret" # not secret

$stdclone.puts $temp.string # secret 1 -> 3

# reset
$stderr = $stdclone
$stderr.puts "secret4" # secret4
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach. As I mentioned in the question, assignment will not be sufficient for me, but the idea of substituting a method might work. I could save the method object, replace it temporarily, then restore it. There may be several methods in addition to `puts` that need to be modified. Perhaps there is a single low level write method that would be the only one needed.

Comment: @KeithBennett you can delegate list of methods as i've just updated on my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that's getting closer to what I need. When restoring to the original behavior, though, I cannot use assignment; there is the risk that the modified $stderr was saved somewhere and retain the behavior change that was supposed to be temporary. We'd need to find way to save the original methods and restore them to $stderr, without changing the object that $stderr points to.