# Printing to file from Ruby pp

Tags: ruby, pretty-print

I'm parsing a JSON file in Ruby and want to output the results using pp to a file.  How can I do that?  Here's the code I'm trying:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
require 'pp'

json = File.read('players.json')
plyrs = JSON.parse(json)

File.open('plyrs.txt', 'a') { |fo| pp page, fo }
```

Comment: And what happens when you run this code?

Comment: plyrs.txt is created but only has a single word of content: 'main'

Comment: possible duplicate of [pretty print to a file in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234899/pretty-print-to-a-file-in-ruby)

Answer (score 3):

`require "rubygems"` is redundant in Ruby >= 1.9.

```
require "json"
require "pp"

plyrs = JSON.load("players.json")
File.open("plyrs.txt", "a"){|io| io.write(plyrs.pretty_inspect)}
```

Comment: this returned: 

/Users/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/json/common.rb:146:in `parse': 710: unexpected token at 'players.json' (JSON::ParserError)
 from /Users/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/json/common.rb:146:in `parse'
 from /Users/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/json/common.rb:294:in `load'
 from print_players.rb:32:in `<main>'

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
require 'pp'

json = File.read('players.json')
plyrs = JSON.parse(json)

File.open('plyrs.txt', 'a') { |file| file.write(pp plyrs) }
```

More info available at the [ruby documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html)