# How can I capture STDOUT to a string?

Tags: ruby, stdio

```
puts "hi"
puts "bye"
```

I want to store the STDOUT of the code so far (in this case hi \nbye into a variable say 'result' and print it )

```
puts result
```

The reason I am doing this is I have integrate an R code into my Ruby code, output of which is given to the STDOUT as the R code runs , but the ouput cannot be accessed inside the code to do some evaluations. Sorry if this is confusing. So the "puts result" line should give me hi and bye.

Comment: If you just want to get the stdout from external program, use result=%x{command}. Otherwise you can redirect stdio like showed by @codegnome

Comment: Are you using `rinruby`? I also tried to catch rinruby (R) output, but up to now without success.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I temporarily redirect stderr in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459330/how-do-i-temporarily-redirect-stderr-in-ruby)

Comment: It's a nit, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459330/how-do-i-temporarily-redirect-stderr-in-ruby refers to `stderr`, this one to `stdout`.  You _could_ merge them, but you'd want a search for "capture stdout" to find an answer as well as "capture stderr".

Answer (score 47, accepted):

### Redirect Standard Output to a StringIO Object

You can certainly redirect standard output to a variable. For example:

```
# Set up standard output as a StringIO object.
foo = StringIO.new
$stdout = foo

# Send some text to $stdout.
puts 'hi'
puts 'bye'

# Access the data written to standard output.
$stdout.string
# => "hi\nbye\n"

# Send your captured output to the original output stream.
STDOUT.puts $stdout.string
```

In practice, this is probably not a great idea, but at least now you know it's possible.

Comment: This is exactly what i need .. but it does not work . can you just have a look at it again please ? its gives a blank output ..even the puts and hi abd byt insdei dont get printed . I have included require stringio .. THanks for the help ..

Comment: No, they *won't* get printed, because you've redirected standard output to your StringIO. Use `STDOUT.puts $stdout.string` to print to the original output stream instead.

Comment: Honestly, this was the only thing that worked for my cases where I wanted to call `Rake::Task[ "mytask" ].invoke` without outputting the result to `STDOUT` and instead capture it for later use. I restore `STDOUT` immediately after using an `ensure` to avoid any issue. This might be dangerous if misused but it works very well when used sparingly.

Answer (score 85):

### A handy function for capturing stdout into a string...

The following method is a handy general purpose tool to capture stdout and return it as a string.  (I use this frequently in unit tests where I want to verify something printed to stdout.)  Note especially the use of the `ensure` clause to restore $stdout (and avoid astonishment):

```
def with_captured_stdout
  original_stdout = $stdout  # capture previous value of $stdout
  $stdout = StringIO.new     # assign a string buffer to $stdout
  yield                      # perform the body of the user code
  $stdout.string             # return the contents of the string buffer
ensure
  $stdout = original_stdout  # restore $stdout to its previous value
end
```

So, for example:

```
>> str = with_captured_stdout { puts "hi"; puts "bye"}
=> "hi\nbye\n"
>> print str
hi
bye
=> nil
```

Comment: Note that this won't necessarily work with, e.g. `Logger`, if it captures a reference to the original `$stdout` before you have a chance to reassign it.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks!  FYI on a cool Ruby trick, if your `begin`/`end` match the duration of your method, you can just skip them and just put the `ensure` at the end of your method (generally the `ensure`/`rescue` is indented at the same level as the method's `def` and `end`)

Comment: @BrianUnderwood: True, but just because you *can* do something in Ruby doesn't always mean you *should* :).  I included the `begin/end` statements mostly to make it easier for newcomers to understand.  Old pros like you will know they can elide the begin/end in this case.

Comment: I agree that there are some things you shouldn't do, but if this is a better syntax I would use it, even for beginners, because I don't think it's likely to confuse (and I love giving people an "I didn't know you could do that" moment even if that wasn't the point of the code).  They say the best way to teach kids complicated words is to not shy away from them

Comment: Does this work with external commands? e.g. should this work? `with_captured_std_out { %x(wget http://google.com) }` I cant get it to work in this context.

Comment: If `%x` is like backticks, it returns a string -- it doesn't print to stdout -- so you neither need nor want to wrap it `with_captured_std_out`.

Comment: Brilliant! One remark: I would use `original_stdout`, instead of `old_stdout`

Answer (score 11):

If activesupport is available in your project you may do the following:

```
output = capture(:stdout) do
  run_arbitrary_code
end
```

More info about `Kernel.capture` can be found [here](http://apidock.com/rails/Kernel/capture)

Comment: ActiveSupport’s Kernel#capture is deprecated and will be removed in some future release, because it’s not thread safe. See [code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e595d91ac2c07371b441f8b04781e7c03ac44135/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb#L90) and [discussion](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/13392).

Answer (score 9):

You can do this by making a call to your R script inside backticks, like this:

```
result = `./run-your-script`
puts result  # will contain STDOUT from run-your-script
```

For more information on running subprocesses in Ruby, check out [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212573/when-to-use-each-method-of-launching-a-subprocess-in-ruby).

Comment: .. this works but the other soln was what i was looking at .. thanks for the reply .. appreciate.

Answer (score 3):

### Capture stdout (or stderr) for both Ruby code *and* subprocesses

```
# capture_stream(stream) { block } -> String
#
# Captures output on +stream+ for both Ruby code and subprocesses
# 
# === Example
#
#    capture_stream($stdout) { puts 1; system("echo 2") }
# 
# produces
# 
#    "1\n2\n"
#
def capture_stream(stream)
  raise ArgumentError, 'missing block' unless block_given?
  orig_stream = stream.dup
  IO.pipe do |r, w|
    # system call dup2() replaces the file descriptor 
    stream.reopen(w) 
    # there must be only one write end of the pipe;
    # otherwise the read end does not get an EOF 
    # by the final `reopen`
    w.close 
    t = Thread.new { r.read }
    begin
      yield
    ensure
      stream.reopen orig_stream # restore file descriptor 
    end
    t.value # join and get the result of the thread
  end
end
```

I got inspiration from [Zhon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21038215/601203).

Answer (score 1):

For most practical purposes you can put anything into `$stdout` that responds to `write`, `flush`, `sync`, `sync=` and `tty?`.

In this example I use a modified [Queue](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Queue.html) from the stdlib.

```
class Captor < Queue

  alias_method :write, :push

  def method_missing(meth, *args)
    false
  end

  def respond_to_missing?(*args)
    true
  end
end

stream = Captor.new
orig_stdout = $stdout
$stdout = stream

puts_thread = Thread.new do
  loop do
    puts Time.now
    sleep 0.5
  end
end

5.times do
  STDOUT.print ">> #{stream.shift}"
end

puts_thread.kill
$stdout = orig_stdout
```

You need something like this if you want to actively act on the data and not just look at it after the task has finished. Using StringIO or a file will have be problematic with multiple threads trying to sync reads and writes simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

`Minitest` versions:

---

`assert_output` if you need to ensure if some output is generated:

```ruby
assert_output "Registrars processed: 1\n" do
  puts 'Registrars processed: 1'
end
```

[assert_output](https://github.com/minitest/minitest/blob/master/lib/minitest/assertions.rb#L331)

---

or use `capture_io` if you really need to capture it:

```ruby
out, err = capture_io do
  puts "Some info"
  warn "You did a bad thing"
end

assert_match %r%info%, out
assert_match %r%bad%, err
```

[capture_io](https://github.com/minitest/minitest/blob/master/lib/minitest/assertions.rb#L542)

`Minitest` itself is available in any Ruby version starting from `1.9.3`

Answer (score 0):

For RinRuby, please know that R has `capture.output`:

```
R.eval <<EOF
captured <- capture.output( ... )
EOF

puts R.captured
```

Answer (score -2):

Credit to @girasquid's answer.  I modified it to a single file version:

```
def capture_output(string)
  `echo #{string.inspect}`.chomp
end

# example usage
response_body = "https:\\x2F\\x2Faccounts.google.com\\x2Faccounts"
puts response_body #=> https:\x2F\x2Faccounts.google.com\x2Faccounts
capture_output(response_body) #=> https://accounts.google.com/accounts
```

Comment: this is a remote code execution vulnerability