# Rails load seed - feedback

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a admin page on my site which allows me to load seeds by clicking a link.

it just calls:

```
Rails.application.load_seed
```

Problem is, there is no feedback that this is happening - I would like to see the seed output somehow on the page (the same as if ran in the command line).

Is there a way to do this when the link is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

If you care about the page reloading, you could use jquery to do an ajax post request to a route, run the script (it doesn't need to be in the seed file--you could run it in the controller action you create) you're running to add data, and then in your success callback append the results.

Comment: does this mean the output would continuously be displayed on the screen, the same as in the console?  I would like user to see it as it happens..

Comment: The user could see it happen. If you want it to be really fast, like a stack trace...you might want to break it up into multiple ajax requests, depending on how much data we're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

If by 'output' you mean messages printed to standard output (e.g. using `puts` in the seeds file), you might grab the output in the controller using the code from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22777806/1544012)):

```
# controller:
@output = with_captured_stdout { Rails.application.load_seed }
```

But this will only display after the load finishes, you won't get any info during the process. If you require that, I think you'd need some streaming techniques.