# How do I store standard outputs to multiple variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, stdout

How do I store Ruby standard outputs to multiple variables?

For example, if I have:

```
puts "hello"

puts "thanks"
```

How do I store "hello" and "thanks" to two different variables like `strVar` (containing the value "hello") and `strVar2` (containing the value "thanks").

In my script, I am calling another Ruby script which will `puts` multiple strings to standard output. How do I store each string from the standard output individually?

Comment: You're trying to capture the standard output of your own script in variables?

Comment: @muistooshort Sort of. In my script, I am calling another ruby script which will puts multiple strings to standard output.  How do I store each string from the standard output individually?  Thanks.

Comment: Although I wouldn't recommend it, [StringIO](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html) is the way to go. Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14988271/1179430)

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand the question, but there are countless numbers of ways to store / print strings.  Its hard to imagine a situation where you would have a value following `puts` that is not entered manually or set programatically.

You can save input variables with gets or $stdin.gets or as an argument with the ARGV array. For example:

```
puts "Enter the first string"
var0 = $stdin.gets.chomp
```

If you already have the values saved

```
var1 = "hello"
var2 = "thanks"
array = [var1, var2]
hash = {:key1 => var1, :key2 => var2}


puts var1
puts var2
array.each do |str| puts str end
hash.map do |k, v| puts v end
```

Comment: Thanks.  But what if I don't have the values saved?  For example, in my case, I call another script in my script so I have no control.  The other scripts has many lines where strings are puts to standout output.

Comment: Maybe you could use pipes? For example, ruby script1.rb | ruby script2.rb and use $stdin.gets to get the output? I don't think there is a way to both execute another ruby script an and also monitor $stdin at the same time within script2. Also what should happen if script1 has an Exception? The proper way to do this is to use a database/redis/filestore and store the values there :)

Comment: Also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987362/how-can-i-capture-stdout-to-a-string

Comment: I think this part is consistent with what I have found so far.  Thanks.  :)

Comment: If you want more control use the [Open3](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html) library and a method like [`popen3`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3) which gives you handles for input, output, errors and a way to wait for that process to finish.

Comment: @tadman Thank you sir.  This is more advanced but works for me.

Comment: It isn't necessary to use `$stdin.gets` because, [by default `gets` reads from the standard input stream](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Kernel.html#method-i-gets), just as it's not necessary to use `$stdout.puts` since [`puts` defaults to the standard output stream](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Kernel.html#method-i-puts).

Answer (score 0):

You're basically chaining applications/scripts together. There are multiple ways to do it but the simplest path uses the STDIN/STDOUT pipeline.

A simple example would be using two small scripts. Save this as test.rb:

```
puts 'foo'
puts 'bar'
```

and this as test2.rb:

```
v1 = gets.chomp
v2 = gets.chomp

puts "v1=#{v1} v2=#{v2}"
```

then, at the command line use:

```
ruby test.rb | ruby test2.rb
```

which will output:

```
v1=foo v2=bar
```

`|` is how we chain the output of one script to the input of another and isn't part of Ruby, it's part of the OS.

This works because, by default, `puts` writes to STDOUT and `gets` reads from STDIN. `|` wires them together.