# Ruby watch stdout of own process

Tags: ruby, logging, vagrant

***Note:  I'm new to Ruby and so the terminology and/or syntax below may be wrong.***

Is there a way to watch STDOUT my ruby process without blocking the rest of my code?  Something like:

```
$stdout.read_lines {|line| // This block is executed on each line logged via `puts`
    do_something() if line == 'some interesting string'
}

puts 'Hello world'
puts 'some interesting string' // This would cause the `do_something` line to be executed
```

I have seen examples where a new process can be created and watched in a similar fashion, but none where the current process's stdout was being watched.

Many thanks.

Edit:

Specifically I am looking to execute some code when this line is executed in my Vagrant setup:  https://github.com/cogitatio/vagrant-hostsupdater/blob/master/lib/vagrant-hostsupdater/HostsUpdater.rb#L103

It looks like the message is logged to @ui which I *believe* is an instance this module https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/blob/master/lib/vagrant/ui.rb

Comment: Possible duplicate -- are you looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22777806/1954610)?

Comment: It is similar.  But, unless I'm misunderstanding the code, that captures the stdout and only makes it accessible after the block has executed.  

I need to continually listen for input without blocking the process.  Also my code has threads which write to stdout that I don't think would get logged by the linked method.

Then again, I could be completely wrong :)

Comment: Listen for **input**? I thought we were only talking about **output**?

Comment: Also, could there not be a cleaner solution for this, e.g. Tell your code two write to a logger - in which you encapsulate all of this logic? Rather than trying to modify the global `$stdout` behaviour?

Comment: Indeed.  Perhaps I should be more specific with my problem...  Please see the edit

Comment: Hmm, interesting... I wonder if you could figure out where `Vagrant:: UI::Interface` gets initialised, then change the value of `@stdout` to use your own `IOStream` that intercepts the behaviour as described above.

Comment: I don't have control over the `Vagrant` or `vagrant-hostsupdater` plugin code base.  My code runs within the `Vagrantfile` (https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/version.html).

Perhaps changing `$stdout` to myown very early on in the VagrantFile will work... but I'm not sure _how_ I can do this?

Comment: Why specifically do you need to run some code at that point in Vagrant? I can't imagine a solution this hacky being the right way to solve your problem.

Comment: You need to work on your imagination!  :)   I want to show a notification (a.k.a growl) on my machine when this occurs.  It is often the case I boot my vagrant machine, only to come back to the terminal a few mins later to discover that it's waiting for me to enter my password.  I would like to avoid this painful disappointment as I fear I might hurt myself/others.