# How to turn off $stdout and $stderr in Ruby

Tags: ruby, stdout, stderr

Is it possible to turn off $stdout and $stderr and not re-direct it to a file; just turn it off so it prints out nothing to anywhere?

I've already tried the following code, but it just errors with `error: Invalid argument`

```
$stderr = IO.new(0,"w")
$stdout = IO.new(0,"w")
```

Comment: *"so it prints out nothing to anywhere"* - printing everything to [nowhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device) is probably easier ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This gist will show you how to redirect to /dev/null:

https://gist.github.com/moertel/11091573

Or this SO answer:

[How do I redirect stderr and stdout to file for a Ruby script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018595/how-do-i-redirect-stderr-and-stdout-to-file-for-a-ruby-script)

Your question probably needs to be marked as a dup.

Comment: I see, I didn't understand what `"/dev/null"` was so I thought it was irrelevant and therefore not related to this question, thanks!

Comment: Links are secondary to a solution. Please provide some code and explanation inline with SO.

Comment: His question should have been marked as a dup.  Note that one of the links is to SO.

Comment: And for portability reasons `IO::NULL` should be used instead of plain `"/dev/null"`.