# ruby: open File object to stdout

Tags: ruby, file, io, stdout

I am quite new with Ruby, and I am trying to open a `File` object that points to `stdout`.

I know from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018595/how-do-i-redirect-stderr-and-stdout-to-file-for-a-ruby-script) that redirecting `stdout` to point to a `File` is quite simple, but what about redirecting a `File` to point to `stdout`?

I am writing a program, and I am thinking of providing the users with the option to write *part* of the output to a file. If they *do not* choose that option, then all of the output should be written to `stdout`.

See this pseudocode:

```
if output redirect option is selected
    o = File.open('given filename','w')
else
    o = File.open($stdout, 'w')
end
```

Here is pseudocode for a possible usecase:

```
puts 'Generating report for XYZ'
report = ReportGenerator::generateReport('XYZ')
o.puts report
```

As you can see, I desire only `o` to put the report to `stdout` if the output redirection option was not specified. The 'Generating report' message, however, I need to still be printed to `stdout`, so redirecting `stdout` will be cumbersome, especially since I have many more messages and many more places in which I am (possibly) alternating between output streams.

`o = File.open($stdout, 'w')` is the part I am uncertain of.

Comment: `o = $stdout` should work in your case.

Comment: ...agh that is so simple thanks. I will try that, and you should put that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ruby's `$stdout` is an [`IO`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html) instance that responds to `puts`, so you can just write:

```
if output_redirect_option_is_selected
  o = File.open('given filename','w')
else
  o = $stdout.dup
end
```

`dup`-ing `$stdout` allows you to close `o` without affecting `$stdout`:

```
o = $stdout.dup
o.close
puts 'bye' # works as expected
```

whereas:

```
o = $stdout
o.close
puts 'bye' # raises IOError
```

Comment: leaving the `dup` method call when assigning `o = $stdout` actually did not raise IOError. Do you think that is because I never closed `o`?

Comment: @ScottScooterWeidenkopf yes, it only happens if you close `o` (i.e. `$stdout`) and write to it afterwards. You should nonetheless close open file handles.