# In Ruby, how do I redirect STDIN to a file

Tags: ruby

This Ruby code hangs:

```
file = File.open('filename')
STDIN = file
do_stuff
file.close
```

So in Ruby, how do I redirect STDIN to a file?

Comment: Some variation of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018595/how-do-i-redirect-stderr-and-stdout-to-file-for-a-ruby-script ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, based on the variation link provided, I got it to work:

```
file = STDIN.reopen('filename')
do_stuff
file.close
```

Thanks!